# What is the easiest way to add a new contact to an existing Google contacts group?

Tags: contacts, contact-groups

Let's say I'm adding a new contact and it's a long lost family members so I want to add them to my custom "Aussie Family" group within my Google account. There appears to be no easy way to do this. I have to log in on a PC to actually achieve the grouping.

I recall reading a similar question somewhere (which I now can't locate) which indicated it's **not possible using the built-in contacts manager**, so, if that's the case, I'm looking for the best way to do it via an app.

I'm using Gingerbread (2.3.3) on a Samsung Galaxy phone (kernel v2.6.35.7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thus far, there appears to be no answer. The best alternative appears to be that you can log into Gmail on a PC and add your new contact to an existing group. Will change the answer to this question if a valid answer pops up.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 running the default 2.3.3 Gingerbread and from within the phone/contacts app, selecting a contact and then scrolling to the groups section allows me to check and uncheck whichever groups I wish this particular contact to be a part of.

Naturally, make sure you're saving your contacts as "Google Contacts" and not simply "Phone Contacts".

Comment: I cannot follow these instructions on my phone. Can you provide a diagram or screenshots? Specifically, there is no "groups section" when I scroll through the details of my Goolge contact. Also, I don't have Galaxy S2, just Galaxy S.

Comment: Unfortunately, this may be particular to the S2 TouchWiz interface, then Lisa - sorry. I'll try posting screenshots later.

Comment: Supposely my phone already has the TouchWiz interface because that also comes with regular Galaxy S (per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_i9000_Galaxy_S infobox) but perhaps I'm mistaken

Comment: Different version of TouchWiz